# Create Linear Layout in Relative Layout Programmatically

Tags: java, android, for-loop, android-linearlayout

Im new to programming so im really sorry, if this question is too easy...

I created an activity which creates an intent with putextra and opens a second activity. The second activity gets the string and shall create a linear layout dynamically in a for loop. The counter of the for loop is the parsed int from getextra.

The problem: The loop is working, but the created content in the for loop does not show up.

XML of the second activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity"
    android:id="@+id/master">
</RelativeLayout>
```

I kept it quite empty, because i want to create the linear layout programmatically as a child of the relative layout.

This is the code from the second activity:

```
package com.example.stopwatchmulti;

import androidx.annotation.ColorInt;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    String ergebnis;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        ergebnis = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Ergebnis");

        int anzahl = Integer.parseInt(ergebnis);

        View master = (View) findViewById(R.id.master);


        // Create Dynamic Linear Layout

       for (int i = 1; i < anzahl + 1; i++) {

            String strI = String.valueOf(i);
            Log.i("Loopnumber",strI);

            LinearLayout layoutZeile = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutZeile.setLayoutParams(linearParams);
            layoutZeile.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            TextView textViewUserNr = new TextView(this);
            textViewUserNr.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,20);
            textViewUserNr.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            textViewUserNr.setText("User");
            layoutZeile.addView(textViewUserNr);

        }
    }
}
```

I tried hours for hours solving this problem. Log.i says the loop itself is working. I also tried it by inflating a second xml with the predefined linear layout, nothing works. I just get a blank screen.

Could you please explain your answers as simple as possible (like to a three year old kid...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of trying and failing, I could create the design by creating a relative layout in the second activity, add a `ListView` to it, define a `ListView` XML and create a custom `ArrayAdapter`.

Main `Activity2` Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity"
    android:id="@+id/master">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/carbonbg2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/customListview"
        android:layout_weight="80">

    </ListView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Next I changed the code in the main class:

```
package com.example.stopwatchmulti;

import androidx.annotation.ColorInt;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Define Variables and Arrays

    String ergebnis;
    int anzahl;

    ArrayList<String> userNummern = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> userNamen = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> userZeiten = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Create Arrays without giving them a value instantly

    String[] userNr;
    String[] userName;
    String[] userZeit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        ergebnis = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Ergebnis");

        anzahl = Integer.parseInt(ergebnis);

        // Add Lines in favour of UserChoice in First activity

        for(int i = 1; i < anzahl + 1; i++) {

            userNummern.add(String.valueOf(i));
            userNamen.add("User"+String.valueOf(i));
            userZeiten.add("00:00:00");
        }

        // Define Values in the Array by transforming Arrailist elements to the arrays

        userNr = userNummern.toArray(new String[0]);
        userName = userNamen.toArray(new String[0]);
        userZeit = userZeiten.toArray(new String[0]);

        // Run Custom ArrayAdapter

        ListView customListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customListview);
        CustomListview customListview1 = new CustomListview(this,userNr,userName,userZeit);
        customListview.setAdapter(customListview1);

    }
}
```

And after all I set up a new class with the custom `ArrayAdapter`:

```
package com.example.stopwatchmulti;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class CustomListview extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


    private String[] userNr;
    private String[] userName;
    private String[] userZeit;

    private Activity context;

    public CustomListview(Activity context, String[] userNr, String[] userName, String[] userZeit) {
        super(context, R.layout.usertableobjects,userNr);

        this.context    = context;
        this.userNr     = userNr;
        this.userName   = userName;
        this.userZeit   = userZeit;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View r = convertView;
        Viewholder viewholder = null;
        if (r==null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            r=inflater.inflate(R.layout.usertableobjects,null, true);
            viewholder=new Viewholder(r);
            r.setTag(viewholder);
        }
        else{
            viewholder = (Viewholder) r.getTag();
        }

        viewholder.tv1.setText(userNr[position]);
        viewholder.tv2.setText(userName[position]);
        viewholder.tv3.setText(userZeit[position]);

        return r;

    }

    class Viewholder{

        TextView tv1;
        TextView tv2;
        TextView tv3;
        Viewholder(View v) {

            tv1 = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewNummer);
            tv2 = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            tv3 = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewZeit);

        }

    }
}
```

That's it, now it works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your forget to put :

```
master.addView(layoutZeile);
```

after

```
layoutZeile.addView(textViewUserNr);
```

Also change the line :

```
View master = (View) findViewById(R.id.master);
```

to:

```
RelativeLayout master = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.master);
```

and it is also necessary to define where the LinearLayout is placed within the RelativeLayout, although it will probably be placed by default in the upper left corner

Comment: If I add it, AndroidStudio says "cannot resolve method 'addView(android.widget.LinearLayout)'

Comment: Now theres only 1 String "User" showing in the top left corner.

Comment: That is exactly what was expected to happen, as I said in my answer

Comment: I edited the params line ``` LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);``` But it didnt work. Still only 1 String "User"  in the top left corner instead of i.e. 5 times "User"

Comment: And setting width and height to the textview gives me again a blank screen

Comment: Trying to create a complete layout with code is really complicated, although if you add several TextViews to one LinearLayout without doing anything else they should be stacked one after other.